# Create WAR file from pom.xml for an existing Maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am creating a web project and I was told that it has to reside inside the resources directory of an existing maven project

Here is the structure of the project

```
MavenProject
  |-- src
  |   |-- main
  |   `-- resources
  |       `-- My-Web-Project
  |           |-- META-INF
  |           |    `-- MANIFEST.MF
  |           |-- src
  |           |   |-- classes
  |           |   |   |-- com
  |           |   |   |   `-- example
  |           |   |   |       `-- projects
  |           |   |   |           `-- SampleAction.class
  |           `-- web
  |               |-- css
  |               |-- css
  |               |-- img
  |               |-- js
  |               |-- WEB-INF
  |               |   `-- web.xml 
  |               |-- index.jsp
  |               `-- secondary.jsp
  |-- test
  `-- pom.xml
```

As you can see there is already a pom.xml file for the MavenProject. I want to be able to deploy my web project WAR using the current pom.xml.

I want to know if it's possible to do this and how would I proceed to create the Maven Plugin.

I read  this article but I don't know if it apply to my situation
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

EDIT:

I am using tomcat app server.

As Mentioned before, My project "My-Web-Project" should be under "resources"

Comment: This is bad idea to put `SampleAction.class` into source directory. Why you are doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read this document, incomplete, but it is good starter.

### [Using Maven When You Can't Use the Conventions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html)

- [Using maven using non standard directory layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603730/using-maven-using-non-standard-directory-layout)

Sample configuration (**not recommended**)

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>src/main/resources/My-Web-Project/web</directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This is not complete, `target` and classes shouldn't be located inside source directory.

---

## Maven convention - recommended solution

> I was told that it (web project) has to reside inside the resources directory of an existing maven project

**This is wrong, web project shouldn't be created inside resources!**

Read about [Maven Convention over Configuration](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-conventionConfiguration.html).

> Convention over configuration is a simple concept. Systems, libraries, and frameworks should assume reasonable defaults. Without requiring unnecessary configuration, systems should "just work".

### Use convention instead of configuration.

Proper directory structure should looks like this:

```
MavenProject
   |-- src
   |   |-- main
   |   |   `-- java
   |   |       `-- com
   |   |           `-- example
   |   |               `-- projects
   |   |                   `-- SampleAction.java
   |   `-- resources
   |   |   `-- META-INF
   |   |       `-- MANIFEST.MF
   |   `-- webapp
   |        |-- css
   |        |-- img
   |        |-- js
   |        |-- WEB-INF
   |        |   `-- web.xml
   |        |-- index.jsp
   |        `-- secondary.jsp
   |-- test
   |-- target  // this is generated by maven!
   |   |-- classes
   |   |   `-- com
   |   |       `-- example
   |   |           `-- projects
   |   |               `-- SampleAction.class
   `-- pom.xml
```

Source: [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: The problem is that I cannot create a new project. My project must reside inside resources. That is given and I cannot change that. My questions is: Can I create the structure you gave inside My-Web-Project and add deployment code in the MavenProject pom?

Comment: Why you cannot? What is the real reason? New project is not needed, there are modules in Maven.

Comment: What should be the plugin xml?

Comment: plugin.xml? I dont understand.

Comment: Proper solution doesn't requires any configuration. Configuration for not recommended solution added.

Comment: Why is it not recommended? The original maven project is not a web project is a java project. I need to add configuration to deploy the war file.

Answer (score 3):

What app server are you using? Most app servers already have its own maven plugin capable of deploying war so you don't have to write yourself: [jboss-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/), [tomcat-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/).

Also your folder structure doesn't comply with [maven standards](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). Typically if you follow the standards and set your archive type into war, on package goal maven will automatically generate a war for you in the target folder.