# Could not open ServletContext resource (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

community.
I am starting work with Spring framework and i've just wanted  to complete a Hello World web application. But these error was happened when i try to run application.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/web/WEB-INF/applicationConfig.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/web/WEB-INF/applicationConfig.xml]
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:642)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:690)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:558)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've read many solutions but none didn't help. I use : maven, spring 5.0.4, IntelijIDEA, Tomcat 8.5.29

File pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ru.ladence.helloweb</groupId>
<artifactId>helloweb</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resources>
                        <directory>WebContent</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.*</include><!--this line includes the xml files into the war, which will be found when it is exploded in server during deployment -->
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resources>
                </webResources>
                <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

File web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/web/WEB-INF/applicationConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I know what there is Spring Context naming convention [servlet-name]-servlet.xml, but it doesn't help

[image: Структура папок в Intelij IDEA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `/web` from the `contextConfigLocation` value

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationConfig.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

as a WAR file should have a top-level `WEB-INF` directory and not `web/WEB-INF`.

Than simplify your `maven-war-plugin` configuration as you are including the resources as they are, without filtering:

```
<configuration>
  <webResources>
    <resources>
      <directory>WebContent</directory>
    </resources>
  </webResources>
</configuration>
```

You might want to use `src/main/webapp` instead of `WebContent` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21173627/1602555).

Comment: it doesn't help :(

Comment: @Ladence when you build the project using Maven, is the `WEB-INF` director included in your WAR file after `mvn clean package`?

Comment: Than I'm puzzled because `maven-war-plugin` in your question is configured to use `<directory>WebContent</directory>` but your WEB-INF is under `web` directory and not `WebContent` directory. One way or another `<param-value>` must reference contents inside the WAR.

Comment: sorry, the directory WEB-INF is included but only web.xml is included in this directory, applicationConfig not

Comment: @Ladence looks like an issue with `<include>` pattern, updated my answer with simplified configuration for `maven-war-plugin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167527/discussion-between-ladence-and-karol-dowbecki).