# How to add Maven to existing Java WebApplication in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

There is standard Java WebApp project. I need to use Maven to build/compile/deploy project to online server. There is an option to create [new maven module](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_and_importing_Maven_projects) module or to import project using pom.xml. Following probaby won't work because:

1. Project doesn't have maven project and `pom.xml`
2. Creating new maven module probably would mess up my existing project structure.

How to add Maven support to existing Java WebApplication in IntelliJ 12?

---

**UPDATE:**

I selected `Add framework Support...` > Maven. Generated `pom.xml` at project's root. Added `maven-war-plugin`. The following structure I have got. Is it any good / correct?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use maven standard project structure for maven applications. However, if you cannot change it, then you have to tell Maven where to look for specific files. Consider:

[Using maven using non standard directory layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603730/using-maven-using-non-standard-directory-layout)

[Standard Maven structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Also here are some interesting things to remember: http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Maven_FAQ